# What happens if you try to counterspell a spell cast by a projected image?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-1e, spellcasting, illusion, counterspelling

A wizard has a [projected image](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/project-image/).
The wizard tries to cast a spell through the projected image.

Someone else has an action ready to cast a dispel magic to counterspell the wizard. The [dispel magic](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dispel-magic/) spell description reads:

> [..]
>   You choose to use dispel magic in one of two ways: a targeted dispel or a *counterspell*.
>   [..]
>   *Counterspell*: When dispel magic is used in this way, **the spell
>   targets a spellcaster** and is cast as a counterspell. Unlike a true
>   counterspell, however, dispel magic may not work; you must make a
>   dispel check to counter the other spellcaster’s spell.

What happens when he casts the dispel?
Does it affect the spell or the projected image?
If it affects the image, what happens to the cast spell? Is it lost?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Nothing happens with the image or the spell.

The description of projected image says:

> If you desire, any spell you cast whose range is touch or greater **can
>   originate from the projected image** instead of from you.

Thus if one chooses the counterspell option when casting dispel magic and chooses the projected image as it’s target spellcaster nothing happens. This is because the text of projected image states that the image is only the origin of the spall (which is still cast by the one who cast projected image).

Comment: Ok, so if I wanted to dispel the projected image, I could either :  
* identify it as a projected image and make a targeted dispel vs a spell (the projected image spell)  
* or try to cast a dispel vs a creature (the image)
Both would work ?

Comment: Yes they both should work.